# How do I get a div's text?

Tags: html, dom, factor-lang

[`html.parser.analyzer`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/vocab-html.parser.analyzer.html) is how to work with HTML, it seems:

```
( sc ) "google.com/search?q=vim" scrape-html

--- Data stack:
T{ response f "1.1" 200 "OK" H{ ~array~ ~array~ ~array~ ~array~...
V{ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~...
( sc ) nip "resultStats" find-by-id

--- Data stack:
258
T{ tag f "div" H{ ~array~ ~array~ } f f }
( sc )  dup .
T{ tag
    { name "div" }
    { attributes H{ { "class" "sd" } { "id" "resultStats" } } }
}

--- Data stack:
258
T{ tag f "div" H{ ~array~ ~array~ } f f }
```

Now, how do I get at that object's text? It should be something like `About 53,000,000 results`. `html.parser.analyzer` doesn't seem to expose the text...?

Edit: Oooh:

```
<div id="resultStats">About 310,000,000 results<nobr> (0.43 seconds)&nbsp;</nobr></div>
```

It's not a `p`, it's a `div`.
So the question is really, how do I get at a div's text?

```
--- Data stack:
T{ tag f "div" H{ ~array~ ~array~ } f f }
( sc ) dup text>>

--- Data stack:
T{ tag f "div" H{ ~array~ ~array~ } f f }
f
```

Not so simple. :(

Comment: factor-lang - see the labels

Comment: @BassemAkl This is about [factor](http://factorcode.org), it's in the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `find-by-id-between`, that will give you everything inside as well as the tag itself (or so it looks like :).

The text will be inside the result, so:

```
( sc ) "google.com/search?q=vim" scrape-html

--- Data stack:
T{ response f "1.1" 200 "OK" H{ ~array~ ~array~ ~array~ ~array~...
V{ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~...
( sc ) nip "resultStats" find-by-id-between

--- Data stack:
T{ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ }
( sc )  dup .
V{
    T{ tag
        { name "div" }
        { attributes
            H{ { "class" "sd" } { "id" "resultStats" } }
        }
    }
    T{ tag
    { name text }
        { text "Cerca de 41.500.000 resultados" }
    }
    T{ tag { name "div" } { attributes H{ } } { closing? t } }
}

--- Data stack:
T{ ~tag~ ~tag~ ~tag~ }
( sc ) second text>>

--- Data stack:
"Cerca de 41.500.000 resultados"
```

It's in spanish because nosy google found out who I am!

Comment: Oh, *that's* what that's for. Thanks!

Comment: If you're curious, the application was here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76314/46231 :P